# Absolute position div not rendering properly when modified within ng-repeat - Chrome specific issue

Tags: css, angularjs, google-chrome

This behavior is somewhat confusing to me, so I would appreciate some external help to understand what is happening.

I have prepared a fiddle to illustrate the behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/cseignc/mfoejqum/

I have an html table whose header is maintained fixed by absolute-positioning a second header via some CSS.

The table is generated thanks to the `ng-repeat` directive that loops through the array of columns and rows.

In order to provide horizontal scrolling, while maintaining the first column and the header fixed, I am filtering the array of columns to `ng-repeat` on by using the `startFrom` and `LimitTo` filters.

I am providing navigation buttons (left and right chevrons) to allow the user to scroll horizontally through the table. Those buttons increment/decrement the value passed to the `startFrom` filter.

This is working as expected for the table body but the second header fails to render properly. I am even finding it impossible to detect consistency in how the second header is rendering - or not.

I initially thought this was to do with `$scope.$apply()` not being called for, but all my code is within AngularJs, so I do not believe that there is a need for calling it...Correct me please if I am wrong.

I have found that resizing the screen will cause the header to render properly.

Any insight on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

EDIT:
The above issues appears to be Chrome specific. I have tested the behaviour in IE and Firefox and the header is rendering correctly in those browsers.

Comment: Everything works for me or i don't understand the problem. 00

Comment: @BroiSatse, when you scroll horizontally via the navigation buttons, the rendering of the header is erratic.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your fiddle that should give you a bit of a start in achieving exactly what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/a06uvkr3/

The gist is that I:

1) initialized `$scope.skip` to 0 in the controller

2) Ditched the `ng-repeat` filters and used `ng-show` with some logic based on `$index`

3) tweaked the CSS so that the header's `.tr-inner` container is absolute rather than the things inside it and gave the header a fixed height. Also tweaked a bit of padding to account for the header items being thrown out a little

Obviously I can't verify that it fits your exact use cases, but you can see the result is much more promising.

Comment: Thanks for your response....Unless I am mistaken, 1) and 2) do not appear to do much. Same behavior with your approach or mine. 3) is removing the absolute position of the div within the ng-repeat. This is causing  the div to render consistently, but it is now out of alignment with the table columns...I think that we are back to my initial question in the title: Why is the div with absolute position not rendering properly if within a ng-repeat when a div without is ?